# Remove previous stack navigating to different stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested stack layout. Each stack has `transparentCard: true` so a background image can be visible. The screenshot below shows the `mainStack` still visible in the background, the Screen in the foreground is a stack nested in a Drawer. How can I remove mainStack in the background?

This only happens on iOS. The old stack doesnt show on Android.

Could I hide it using `transitionConfig`?

[image]

When navigating to a route in a different stack, the previous stack is visible underneath. How can I remove the previous stack?

```
const withHeader = (
    screen: Function,
    routeName: string,
    Header
): StackNavigator =>
    createStackNavigator(
        {
            [routeName]: {
                screen,
                navigationOptions: ({ routeName, props }) => ({
                    header: props => <Header {...props} />
                })
            }
        },
        {
            transparentCard: true
        }
    );

const routes = {
    VideoEpisodes: {
        screen: withHeader(VideoEpisodesScreen, "Video Episodes", DrawerHeader)
    },
...
    About: {
        screen: withHeader(AboutScreen, "About", DrawerHeader)
    }
};

const NestedDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(routes, config);

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
            ...
        },
        Drawer: {
            screen: NestedDrawer,
            ...
        },
        VideoPlayer: {
            screen: VideoPlayerScreen,
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        mode: "card",
        transparentCard: true,
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
        tintColor: "#ffffff",
        headerMode: "screen"
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(MainStack);
```

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // do stuff while splash screen is shown
    // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }
  render() {
    const { videos } = this.props;

    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/images/TC_background.jpg")}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <AppNavigator
            ref={navigatorRef => {
              NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
            }}
          />
        </PersistGate>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

In `componentDidMount`, on the new stack (HomeScreen) I've put the reset to hide the previous stack (MainStack):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Home" })]
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }
```

However, it just navigates me back to the home screen of the previous stack (MainStack). I just need to hide it instead. Any ideas?

I've set up nested `StackNavigators` so I can have the appropriate headers showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the previous stack using the `reset` method like this:

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'routeToResetTo' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

If you can't do this due to unavailability of this.props.navigation, use a `NavigationService.js` like this:

```
// NavigationService.js

import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function reset(index, actions) {
  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index,
    actions
  });
  _navigator.dispatch(resetAction);
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  reset,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

And use it like this:

```
import {reset} from "NavigationService.js"
reset(0, //your actions here);
```

Read more about actions [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html) and about NavigationService [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using navigate? or push? Either way, if you don't need to stack then when going back, you can use this.props.navigation.replace instead of push/navigate.

It is used like this:

```
this.props.navigation.replace("SomeScreen", { someParams: someValue });
```

There is also StackActions and NavigationActions like [@thecodrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6414944/thecodrr) said.

Comment: I am using navigate, but I just need to hide the stack I've navigated from, as it appears beneath the new stack as the card is transparent. `Reset` sends me back to the previous stack, and doesn't hide it, any ideas how I can hide it?

Comment: I would replace everyscreen if i needed than staccked and hidden, even when pressing hardwarebackbutton until reaching the key 0.